# How to convert Android tv apk build to samsung tpk build?

Tags: android, apk, android-tv, samsung-smart-tv, samsung-mobile-sdk

I searched all over internet . they suggest some online conversion tool . but currently (Oct/2023) I checked that site are not in active .Anyone know how to convert android apk to tpk ?

Need to convert apk to tpk format

Comment: By "conversation tool", do you mean "conversion tool"? Also, please include the name of the "online conversation tool".

Comment: Do you have the source code that was used to build the apk file? Perhaps, you could build a tpk file from source, rather than converting an apk file to a tpk file :)

Comment: I tried POLARIS App Generator . can't able to found that site

Comment: I am using react native . can able to generate tpk file format ?

Comment: as per my knowledge Samsung tv support web app . mostly they are using reactjs .

Answer (score 0):

I found an website. You can try this to convert your APK to TPK.

https://converter.tips/convert/apk-to-tpk